# How can I disable the battery?

Tags: 18.04, power-management, battery

My X1 Carbon battery just died without any warning.

On my second notebook (running Windows), I got warnings a few weeks ago that the battery is malfunctioned and needs replacement. And when the battery died, I just disabled the battery from the Device Manager.

Is there a way to do the same? I mean to disable the battery completely so I don't see any battery on my navbar (plugged in, not charging)

Comment: You may try [this](https://support.lenovo.com/ie/en/solutions/pd025206)

Comment: This one is to temporary disable the battery for servicing the laptop.

Answer (score 3):

**Gnome settings**

Actualy it should be possible to disable it by setting:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active false
```

but for some reason it doesn't work anymore.

**GNOME Shell extensions**

However, there are GNOME Shell extensions that you may try to workaround it.

- [Icon Hider](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/351/icon-hider/) - may help you remove parts of gnome panel, but the battery icon is probably a part of aggregateMenu, so removing it will also remove whole power/settings menu
- [Extend Panel Menu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1201/extend-panel-menu/) - but with this exention you can split aggregateMenu into separate icons and then use extension's setting to disable one of them

Edit: **beware**, I found one of these extensions conflicting with my Ubuntu setup. I had to remove them because my Gnome desktop wasn't loading (I had only black screen with just cursor on it). In case it happens [switch to anoher TTY](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167386/how-to-switch-between-tty-and-xorg-session), log in and type:

```
cd .local/share
mv gnome-shell gnome-shell.bak
```

then reboot

**Pretending you are not on laptop**

There's a APT package called [laptop-detect](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/laptop-detect.1.html).

> This package provides a simple shell script which attempts to determine whether it is being run on a laptop (or similar portable machine). It is mainly useful for installers.

While runing this script in debug mode:

```
laptop-detect -D
```

it brings the idea of tricking GNOME that you're not on a laptop.

It might be useful if you want to work on AC-only, with i.e. disassembled battery.

I won't tell you how to do this, but you might want to try to figure it out on your own, based on laptop-detect output.

One thing is for example `/sbin/modprobe battery`. So first step will be to blacklist this module with modprobe config.

Another thing is `/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/chassis_type`, but it's more tricky, because it's related to Linux kernel and changing this value may even require changing its source code somwhere in [drivers/firmware/dmi-id.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/6f0d349d922ba44e4348a17a78ea51b7135965b1/drivers/firmware/dmi-id.c#L58). It's rather something for hardcore linux users ;)

Other places related to laptop battery (for the sake of google-searches):

- /sys/class/power_supply
- /proc/acpi/battery
- /proc/apm