# How to remove the battery icon from the topbar and stop estimating battery life?

Tags: power-management, icons, battery, top-bar

I have moved to ubuntu(21.04) from Windows recently. So I know very little about linux.
I have an old laptop and its battery is dead. I run the laptop directly from the charger. At the topbar it keeps showing the battery icon which is trying to estimate the battery life and disappears in a second. This keeps going all the time. This is very annoying to me. So I am trying to find a way to remove the battery icon from topbar and stop estimating battery life.

I have tried `sudo apt-get remove indicator-power` which shows

> Package 'indicator-power' is not installed, so not removed

Comment: will it disappear if you remove the battery from the laptop?

Comment: @24601, the reference is for GNOME Shell, not Unity.

Comment: @galexite and it didn't solve the problem...

Comment: Yes, I realised after looking again, apologies for that!

Comment: This answer is a bit more complicated than it should be, and the first `gsettings` command doesn't work, but these extensions might provide a workaround? https://askubuntu.com/a/1143362/287379

Comment: The problem is, that the 'Extend Panel Menu' extension is not compatible with the GNOME Shell which comes with 21.04...

Comment: @24601  When I remove the battery problem is solved automatically. But I want it solved with the battery inserted in the laptop. Without the battery the laptop looks bad :)

Comment: @galexite  That answer is very complicated and seems it won’t work.

Comment: That works because Linux automatically recognises the battery presence in the same way it does on a desktop connected to a UPS. Aesthetics aside, I don't think you will find a better solution tbh

Comment: @RaisiBiden I think it would be worth filing a feature request to the GNOME Shell community to introduce a new configuration flag to be able to disable the battery icon. Alternatively as a workaround, and rather hesitantly as a GNOME user, you can choose another desktop environment, like `xubuntu-desktop` or `kubuntu-desktop`, which provide far more configuration. There, you can simply right click the panel, and remove the icon entirely.

Comment: @RaisiBiden removing the icon is possible but "stop estimating" seems tough.

Comment: @UnKNOWn  Can you tell me how?

Comment: Sure, I will write the command now.

Comment: `gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu._power.hide();'`